# Batch Script to Copy files with long filename extensions

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that (robo)copies files from different folders, but this batch script copies ALL files for each of the folders. Please see below batch script.

I have files in the source folders whose format is `.xxx.xxxxxxxxxx` and `.xxx`.

For example, in `folder A`, I have 3 files:

```
12345678901234.001.0423201154
23456789012345.005.0423201155
43210987654321.001
```

I want to copy only the first 2 files to `folder B` above and not include the last file.

Please help. Thanks!

```
@echo off

set Source=\\TestSource
set Target=\\TestTarget
set FolderList=C:\temp\tstsource.txt
set LogFolder=C:\temp\Logfolder\

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FolderList%" echo File list "%FolderList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FolderList%"') do (
     @echo Copying %%a folders and files, please wait ... 
     @echo "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%\%%a" /MOV /DCOPY:DAT /MIR /E /MT:16 /R:2 /W:30 /LOG:"%LogFolder%%%a.log"
     robocopy "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%\%%a" /MOV /DCOPY:DAT /E /MT:16 /R:2 /W:30 /LOG:"%LogFolder%%%a.log"
     @echo.
     @echo *..........................................................
)

:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a pipe to `findStr` in the `for` command to exclude any unwanted file patterns from your `FolderList` file when `type`ing it.

Example:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FolderList%" ^| findStr /I /V /R /C:"^[01234567890]*\.[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]$"') do (
   ...
)
```

You can execute `findStr /?` in a cmd.exe command window to read the documentation about syntax and regular expressions.

Essentially `/I` is for "ignoring case", `/V` is for "exclude/skip the matches" and `/R` means "use regular expression parsing".
The pipe symbol must be escaped inside the for statement for which the caret is used (`^|`).

This RegEx should match the unwanted file patterns:
`"^[01234567890]*\.[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]$"`

With this I assumed that your filenames only consists of digits, which can be denoted as class of symbols in brackets `[0123456789]*` and the asterisk means "repetitions of zero or more times allowed".
The dot must be escaped `\.` because in a regular expression the dot stands for "any single character" (`.*` therefore is "a sequence of any number of characters, zero or more").
The group of three classes after the dot mean "three occurances of digits 0-9", to match the file extension.
The caret `^` at the beginning of the RegEx means "from the start of the line" and the dollar `$` denotes "end of the line" (that is, no spaces after the last digit would be allowed for example).

It is possible to shorten the RegEx a bit by using `[0-9]` or `[a-z]` for lowercase letters and `[A-Z]` respectively, instead of the explicit listing of allowed characters/digits in a class. This might have hard to track side effects, so usually I always list all allowed characters explicitly.

Edit: I missed the part, that you only want to copy the first two file patterns. In this case you could leave out the `/V` and look for files with 2 dots, like this: `"[01234567890]*\.[0123456789]*\.[0123456789]*"` which accepts any number of digits separated by two dots.

Your approach on matching on length of filename+extension should work equally well. If you like to have a minimal or fixed amount of symbols to allow, use the dot as placeholder for exactly one symbol (digit or character). (As seen in the  comments below)

Comment: Looking at the code, I was thinking about comparing lengths of filenames.  
For example, the first 2 are constantly 27 digits, excluding the dots (.).
The last one is only 14 digits long, and this won't be copied to folder B.
I think that is the best way to copy the 2 files:

If length of filename is>14 then copy the file to folder B
Else skip to the next filename

I think this is the way.

Thank you Antares for your suggestion and idea.

Comment: To make it short: robocopy only whose length of filenames+ext (without the .) is 27 characters/digits. How can I incorporate this on my batch script? Thank you for helping.

Comment: The most simple RegEx that comes to my mind is: 27 dots. Maybe enclosed in caret and dollar, like "^.................$". And without the /V switch of course, since you only want to include those matches with 27 arbitrary characters. If you want specifically digits to match, there need to be 27 repetitions of [0123456789].

Comment: Depending on how you use that information, you have to consider the separating dot after the filename as well. Making it 28 dots. Or "...24 repetitions total...\...." when you want to match the separating dot specifically and allow exactly three symbols as extension..